# JPA Design Model For OneToMany Relation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a database design like this: `tb_address( id, address )` and `tb_store( id, name, address_id )` and `tb_user( id, name, address_id )` where both `address_id` are a reference key of tb_address. 
I want to design java model using `spring-data-jpa`. I had already create model one by using tool in `Intellij` to generate database script, but I am not getting what I want. What I got is like this `tb_address( id, address, store_id, user_id )` and I don't want that. So Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't get what you want because of the design of your `Models` or `Entities`. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "td_address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String address;

    //getters and setters

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_store")
public class Store {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;

    //getters and setters

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I got it now. I'm confusing myself. Anyways, thanks you :D